# Get indication when process closed - QT

Tags: qt, process

I'm writing desktop application in QT.
In my application I'm openening another application by the class

```
QProcess *myProcess;
myProcess->start(path + argStr);
```

i would like to get indication if the process is close( maybe by someone manullay)
so i start a new thread

```
void processExitDetector::run()
 {
       connect(myProcess,SIGNAL(finished(int)),this, SLOT (stop()));
 }


void processExitDetector::stop()
 {

 }
```

but if  have breakpoing in the function stop(). i never stop there, even if i'm stopping the process.
what i'm doing worng? what the best way to get indication when the process stopped?

Comment: Hmm. You have just updated your code and removed the `waitForFinished` which changes the context a bit. Are you not doing that after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have the concept of SIGNAL/SLOT a bit backwards. You don't need to wait for the exit of the QProcess in a thread to make the connection. Its the connection of the signal to to the slot that should be telling you when its done.

You have the right idea with [QProcess.finished()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html#finished), but there is no need to start a thread solely to block on `waitForFinished`. Basically the connection you are making is pointless.

1. Create the process
2. Connect the signal
3. Start the process

```
QProcess *myProcess;  
connect(myProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(processFinished()));  
myProcess->start(path + argStr);
```

`processFinished()` is just the SLOT you have defined (or using a built in SLOT) to be notified when your process is done.